# get list name in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

how to get current used list name. my scnerio is: i have a list said config. i have create one column say "test" whose datatype is "Managed Metadata". now after add this column.now  when i edit this item and click on icon near to "test" column one dialog is open which is webtaggig.aspx something like that.

now, i had open my custom control in this page. when page opened , my control is loaded.
now on my custom control page load i want to get the list name programatically.

can any one suggest me how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the SPContext object.  You would need something like SPContext.Current.List.Title to get the name or title of the current list.